# Al actualizar flutter tengo error con GetMaterialApp en mi navegación de rutas

Tags: flutter, dart, bug

Actualice flutter a la última versión e intento probar mi app pero obtengo el siguiente error con la mayoría de rutas, cabe destacara que mis rutas si tienen slash, dejaré mi main.dart para referencia

> You are trying to use contextless navigation without
> a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
> If you are testing your app, you can use:
> [Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
> a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
> for a [GetMaterialApp].

```
import 'package:TendaGo/routes/app_pages.dart';
import 'package:TendaGo/utils/translations.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'global_widgets/global_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'modules/splash/splash_binding.dart';
import 'modules/splash/splash_page.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
 // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await GetStorage.init();
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(TendaGo());
}

class TendaGo extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Get.put(GlobalController());
   return GetMaterialApp(
      unknownRoute: GetPage(
       name: "/splash",
       page: () => SplashPage(),
    ),
    initialRoute: '/splash',
  translations: Messages(),
  locale: Get.deviceLocale,
  fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
  localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('es', 'ES'), // Arabic, no country code
  ],
  theme: ThemeData(
      primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: Colors.white,
  )),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Tenda Go',
  home: SplashPage(),
  initialBinding: SplashBinding(),
  getPages: AppPages.pages,
);
 }
}
```

Por ejemplo: Estoy en mi lista de carritos (vacío el carrito), luego navego a un search para buscar el producto, agrego un producto al carrito y retorno a mi lista de productos que está en un search luego vuelvo a mi carrito y si quiero volver al search, obtengo el siguiente error con                                   Get.toNamed(Routes.DETALLEPRODUCTO)

```
`class AppPages {
 static final List<GetPage> pages = [
 GetPage(
    name: Routes.SPLASH,
    page: () => SplashPage(),
    binding: SplashBinding(),
    transition: Transition.zoom,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.HISTORIAL,
    page: () => HistorialPage(),
    binding: HistorialBinding(),
    transition: Transition.zoom,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.TABS,
    page: () => TabsPage(),
    binding: TabsBinding(),
    transition: Transition.zoom,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.DETALLEPRODUCTO,
    page: () => DetalleProductoPage(),
    binding: DetalleProductoBinding(),
    // transition: Transition.zoom,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.DETALLEPEDIDO,
    page: () => DetallePedidoPage(),
    binding: DetallePedidoBinding(),
    // transition: Transition.zoom,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.DETALLEPEDIDOPAGO,
    page: () => DetallePedidoPago(),
    binding: DetallePedidoPagoBinding(),
    // transition: Transition.zoom,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.LOGIN,
    page: () => LoginPage(),
    binding: LoginBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.CLIENTE,
    page: () => ClientePage(),
    binding: ClienteBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.EDITARCLIENTE,
    page: () => EditarClientePage(),
    binding: EditarClienteBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.CARRITO,
    page: () => CarritoPage(),
    binding: CarritoBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.EDITARPRODUCTO,
    page: () => EditarProductoPage(),
    binding: EditarProductoBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.LOCAL,
    page: () => LocalPage(),
    binding: LocalBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.MAPA,
    page: () => MapaPage(),
    binding: MapaBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.CREAR_CLIENTE,
    page: () => CrearClientePage(),
    binding: CrearClienteBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.STOCK_PRODUCTO,
    page: () => StockProducto(),
    binding: StockProductoBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.CONFIGURACION,
    page: () => ConfiguracionPage(),
    binding: ConfiguracionBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.IDIOMA,
    page: () => IdiomaPage(),
    binding: IdiomaBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.HISTORIALCOTIZACION,
    page: () => HistorialCotizacionPage(),
    binding: HistorialCotizacionBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.COBROS,
    page: () => CobrosPage(),
    binding: CobrosBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.COBROS,
    page: () => AjusteInventarioPage(),
    binding: AjusteInventarioBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.PRODUCTO,
    page: () => ProductoPage(),
    binding: ProductoBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.PRECIO,
    page: () => PrecioPage(),
    binding: PrecioBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.CREARPRODUCTO,
    page: () => CrearProductoPage(),
    binding: CrearProductoBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.MODIFICARPRODUCTO,
    page: () => ModificarProductoPage(),
    binding: ModificarProductoBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.FACTURAR,
    page: () => FacturarPage(),
    binding: FacturarBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.ESTABLECERPRECIO,
    page: () => EstablecerPrecioPage(),
    binding: EstablecerPrecioBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.AGREGARPRECIO,
    page: () => AgregarPrecioPage(),
    binding: AgregarPrecioBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.EDITARPRECIO,
    page: () => EditarPrecioPage(),
    binding: EditarPrecioBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
GetPage(
    name: Routes.AJUSTEINVENTARIO,
    page: () => AjusteInventarioPage(),
    binding: AjusteInventarioBinding(),
    transition: Transition.fadeIn,
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
   ];
 }`
```

Mi sistema de rutas es la siguiente:

```
abstract class Routes {
static const SPLASH = '/';
static const HISTORIAL = '/historial';
static const TABS = '/tabs';
static const DETALLEPRODUCTO = '/detalle_producto';
static const DETALLEPEDIDO = '/detalle_pedido';
static const DETALLEPEDIDOPAGO = '/detalle_pedido_pago';
static const LOGIN = '/login';
static const CLIENTE = '/cliente';
static const EDITARCLIENTE = '/editar_cliente';
static const CARRITO = '/carrito';
static const EDITARPRODUCTO = '/editar_producto';
static const LOCAL = '/local';
static const MAPA = '/mapa';
static const CREAR_CLIENTE = '/crear_cliente';
static const STOCK_PRODUCTO = '/stock_producto';
static const CONFIGURACION = '/configuracion';
static const IDIOMA = '/idioma';
static const HISTORIALCOTIZACION = '/historial_cotizacion';
static const COBROS = '/cobros';
static const PRODUCTO = '/producto';
static const AJUSTEINVENTARIO = '/ajuste_inventario';
static const PRECIO = '/precio';
static const CREARPRODUCTO = '/crear_producto';
static const MODIFICARPRODUCTO = '/modificar_producto';
static const FACTURAR = '/facturar';
static const ESTABLECERPRECIO = '/establecer_precio';
static const AGREGARPRECIO = '/agregar_precio';
static const EDITARPRECIO = '/editar_precio';
}
```

Comment: podrías indicar en que parte haces la navegación? agrega esa parte del código

Comment: El error es relacion con Get.toNamed(Routes.DETALLEPRODUCTO) al haber ya usado Get.back() para regresar a mis páginas anteriores, edite mi respuesta explicando el detalle el problema

Comment: agrega tu clase `AppPages`

Comment: He editado la pregunta y agregando mi sistema de rutas

Comment: es raro, si todo lo haces a través de Get.to, no debería tener problemas.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver, usaba un Get.reset() en el método onClose() al salir de mi pantalla y eso hacía eliminar mis rutas, entonces al querer ir a una ruta nueva en memoria ya no existe

Comment: ya veo, puedes agregar tu solución aquí para que quede registrada y luego la marcas como resuelta

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver, usaba un Get.reset() en el método onClose() al salir de mi pantalla y eso hacía eliminar mis rutas, entonces al querer ir a una ruta nueva en memoria, esa ruta ya no existe.